How can I log pings in OkHttpClient when setting pingInterval?
I use OkHttpClient as a WebSocket client. I set pinging every 10 seconds:
private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .pingInterval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(websocketInterceptor)
    .build()

...

webSocket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, object : WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        Timber.d("Websocket connection opened, response: $response")
    }
    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        Timber.d("Received: $text") // This callback works properly and I receive messages
    }

The problem is that our backend doesn't detect pings. So I am looking for evidences that pings are being sent. I tried to use Interceptor for this:
class WebsocketAuthInterceptor() : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        Timber.d("interceptor request: ${chain.request()}")
        ...
    }
}

But nothing is logged here. My questions are:

How can I detect that pings are being sent from the client?
Is setting .pingInterval(...) enough to send pings to server when using WebSockets?

